# Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: ubuntu, path, set

I am trying to run a program in a server with Linux Ubuntu 3.16.0-31-generic and it gives me the following error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libmpich.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have searched through the internet to find a solution, and I see people talking about setting the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** somehow. Most of the ways to do it required sudo, but I don't have administrator permission, so I cannot use it.

Would this indeed this  solve the problem? And if yes, how could I set it?

Comment: You should be more specific about what you are doing. Most software is installed through your distribution's repositories and are expected to work out of the box without any hack. You are apparently doing something nonstandard and as such you should describe it in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need permission to set this [`ENV` (see the section on 'environment variables')](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-environment.htm) variable.

And because the shared object is missing when *running* vs. *installing* an application, you shouldn't need to set this at all. You are missing a package that includes `libmpich.so`. Seek out and install anything from your "deb" package repository that includes the `libmpich.so` shared object(s). Try the following to find it/them.

```
$ apt-cache search mpich
```

Now back to the question;

There are a few ways to accomplish this. Set it yourself for the entire session, set it permanently, or tell the compiler only during compile time.

The quickest and least intrusive (regarding changing OS environment variables) is to set it for the compile procedure:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64 run-binary-command
```

Or you can set it for the current session like so:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64
```

And to set it forever:

```
$ echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64' >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: Use `:` for path separator, not `;`.  Otherwise you will get errors like `-bash: /lib64/: Is a directory`.  Consult [ld.so manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) for valid environment variable settings.

Comment: Shoot, good catch! Updated.