# "error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"?

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to run and image processing program using ubuntu as a window 10 subssytem and keep getting this error

error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

i am a newbie at linux, any help would be kind.

Thank you

Comment: What program is it? How did you install it and how do you run it?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run a very old application - libpng15.so.15 has long been deprecated and cannot be even installed from the official Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

First things first!

Make sure that the lib exists. (If you had provided evidence of this, it would have been easier)

Secondly, copy that to the current working directory (from where you are starting that process).

Another alternative is to [set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206646/setting-ld-library-path?rq=1) to the location where the lib exists; then try running from that very shell.

Hope this works :-)