# How to make path to current directory visible in bash, in order to be seen by linker?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, linker

I am trying to load shared library, but I dont have its .so file in directory loader look for, So I want to set a environment dir.

```
$ ls # (current dir is bindir)
foo.c foo.h libfoo.so exe
$ path_to_dir=/home/user/bindir
$ $path_to_dir ./exe "bla bla"
bash: /home/user/bindir: Is a directory
```

This may be trivial, But i do not usually run program with modified environment variables, so how to set it?

If I tried to `$ export path_to_dir`, and run it:

```
$ ./exe "bla bla"
./_exe: error while loading shared libraries: libfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So how to modify the environment variable of my dir?

EDIT:
according to this tutorial: [youtube library tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbHmin2Wtmc), the linker cannot see the library (`libfoo.so`, in my case) file, becuase it does not search my current dirctory. The standard libraries `ld` uses, I get by this:

```
$ld --verbose | grep -i search_dir | awk '{print $1}' RS=';'
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib")
```

So the intend between the variable `$path_to_dir` and those above is, that I want to make my directory visible to `ld` by making the `$path_to_dir` as environment variable (also tried `export`, but as you see - to no avail). So how to make visible my dir to `ld` in order to "see" my library and link it with the position-independet program (exe)?

Comment: See if this helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206646/setting-ld-library-path

Comment: @AndyDalton, thanks, but that is about package installation, but not reall library compilation. I could set the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (which I did with the `$path_to_dir`, but as you see, the envirnoment did not accept it. It should be somthing with the envirnoment accepting directories as variables, but not sure with this

Comment: @Herdsman I don't see anything specific to package installation in the link provided - please try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/bindir ./exe "bla bla"` before dismissing it

Comment: @steeldriver that works, but only it the variable is assigning at same line the program is invoked (as in you example). However If I firstly set the variable, and the use it such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/bindir; $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./dynamic_exe "bla bla"`, that does not work. Why?

Comment: ... because that's just how the syntax works: your second command would try to execute `/home/user/bindir` with parameters `./dynamic_exe` and `bla bla`. You can **either** set an environment variable for a particular process using `VAR=value process` as shown **or** for all subsequent processes by exporting it i.e. `export VAR=value`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a typo:

```bsh
$path_to_dir ./exe "bla bla"
```

This calls `$path_to_dir` with two arguments.
It likely should be

```bsh
$path_to_dir/exe "bla bla"
```

This calls one executable with one argument.
You can also set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the same invocation:

```bsh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PWD $path_to_dir/exe "bla bla"
```

Comment: but that does not set the environment. It is the same as ./exe, and that invokes the error above